# Opencv cvshow image cannot get the focus

Tags: windows, image, opencv

I use opencv to show raw images, images look ok however I cannot click and drag the windows or cannot bring them to focus. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing `cv::waitKey` call.

Please read [the documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html#waitkey) and [some tutorials](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/tutorials.html) to understand OpenCV GUI functions.